# Access KV store and Environment Variables in G-WAN using MONO

Tags: mono, key-value-store, g-wan

I got mono 3.0.6 working with G-WAN and now I am trying to use G-WAN persistent pointers and KV Store using mono but don't know how to do it.

G-WAN does expose some functions on **gwan_api.cs** but the KV function and get_env is not there.

Is it possible to access this in mono?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to access G-WAN's KV store in C# scripts?

No, and here is why.

We initially tried the wrappers we wrote but, like for JNI, the mandatory conversion overhead is defeating the purpose of light and fast calls.

Like Java, C# offers a plethora of solutions for almost everything G-WAN does natively and this is what should be used if you use either language.

Note that part of your application can be written in C/C++/D/Objective-C/Objective-C++ and call all the native G-WAN API directly while the rest of your application may use C# or Java.

That's the advantage for an Application Server to support different programming languages.

Comment: Can we make our own wrappers like `[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
extern public static string http_status (int code);`

Comment: That's roughly what we did, but you also have to take care of data conversions, and this is what slows-down the G-WAN API to levels that defeat its primary purpose: efficiency.